# Upload Markdown files to Wiki as part of Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-wiki

As part of an Azure Pipeline to build a Python package and store it in Azure Artifacts I'm generating a lot of `.md` files from the docstrings as documentation for the package. I'd like to add a step to my pipeline to automatically upload those to the Azure DevOps Wiki. Is this possible? From the official documentation I could only find a way to do it manually from a folder in the [repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up cloning the wiki repository and subsequently adding and committing the generated files as part of the pipeline step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rest Api to update Wiki pages: [Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

Here you can find a sample with PowerShell: https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/UpdateWikiPage.ps1